# Can I use Stash inside Third Party Module Tags?

Tags: stash, module, variable

in the examples of Stash and every other similar plugin I always see the variables being set inside the channel:entries tag. But what if I need to set a tag inside the tag of another module? Like for example Solspace's Rating module? Have a look at the code below:

Here I'm trying to set a Stash variable...

```
{exp:rating:stats}
  {exp:stash:set name="rating"}{overall_rating}{/exp:stash:set}
{/exp:rating:stats}
```

Here I attempting to output it...

```
{exp:stash:get name="rating"}
```

But this isn't working with Stash or the String plugin which I also tried.

It seems like I can only set variables inside the channel:entries tag. Is this true?
Is there no way to store variables for later use inside third party module tags such as Solspace's Ratings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes anything's possible when you get your head around parse order. There are several different ways of doing this, but generally I find it easiest to always put Stash on the outside of other tags (regardless of whether they're third party or not):

```
{exp:stash:set parse_tags="yes"}
    {exp:rating:stats}
        {stash:rating}{overall_rating}{/stash:rating}
        {stash:something-else}{another_thing}{/stash:something-else}
    {/exp:rating:stats}
{/exp:stash:set}

Rating: {exp:stash:get name="rating"}
```

Comment: Hi, I just played around with that code, but I can't get it to work. I will look into the getting a better understanding of the parse order though.

Comment: Can you post more of your template?

Comment: Played around a but more an got it working, thanks! :D